# Endless draw/undraw SVG path loop using vanillaJS

Tags: javascript, css, loops, for-loop, svg

I would like to add a class and remove a class to an svg path every time the animation in the previous path has ended, to achieve a smooth drawing/undrawing effect over and over.

My fiddle shows what I mean, but I am only listening for animationend, then undrawing the path. I'm unsure what the best way to loop through endlessly is. The current fiddle draws and undraws once (remove .patha and add .pathb) but then doesn't trigger on the next animationend.

To get a smooth continuous animation I would need to alternate like so add(.pathb)>>remove(.patha)>>add(.pathc)>>remove(.pathb)>>add(.pathd)>>remove(.pathc)>>add(.patha)>>remove(.pathd)

I was thinking of a for loop, using the % operator but that does not seem optimal. For now, I can't even trigger the animation end to trigger every time the animation ends, only once.

https://jsfiddle.net/jr7ocbzq/4/
relevant JS snippet:

```
svgpath.addEventListener("animationend", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("path").classList.add('pathb');
  document.getElementById("path").classList.remove('patha');
  i++;
  console.log(i);
}, false);
```

To reiterate for clarity, trying to toggle from the element having the class patha to pathb then pathc then pathd in that sequence, endlessly. All the potential solutions I found were jQuery, not vanillaJS. Need to trigger an onEvent every animationend, so one continuous one doesn't work.

Comment: It's still not clear why a solution that doesn't swap classes but does look visually identical is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need an array of those 4 class names, and then you can cycle through them:

```js
const svgpath = document.getElementById("path");
const paths = ['patha', 'pathb', 'pathc', 'pathd'];
let i = 0;
svgpath.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
  svgpath.classList.remove(paths[i]);
  i = (i + 1) % 4;
  svgpath.classList.add(paths[i]);
}, false);
```

```css
.patha {
  stroke-dasharray: 13672.7;
  stroke-dashoffset: -13672.7;
  animation: dashZero 1s linear forwards;
}

.pathb {
  stroke-dasharray: 13672.7;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dashDrawn 1s linear forwards;
}

.pathc {
  stroke-dasharray: 13672.7;
  stroke-dashoffset: 13672.7;
  animation: dashZero 1s linear forwards;
}

.pathd {
  stroke-dasharray: 13672.7;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dashUndrawn 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dashZero {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dashDrawn {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 13672.7;
  }
}

@keyframes dashUndrawn {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -13672.7;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 3027.621 4035.496" enable-background="new 0 0 150 200" xml:space="preserve">
      <path id="path" class="patha" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="16" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M413.078,1768.305
        c-24.633,50.051-0.718,112.339,6.712,163.942c9.629,66.869,23.438,133.097,36.056,199.496
        c22.431,118.04,30.003,240.334,26.476,359.948c-3.251,110.267,14.797,239.577,71.273,335.987
        c14.709,25.109,29.367,50.25,43.714,75.568c9.666,19.331,28.359,31.145,41,48c14.109,20.522,29.366,40.521,48,57.186
        c23.089,20.648,51.639,30.456,74.625,51.064c20.852,18.695,45.92,32.317,66.834,51.288c17.762,16.109,30.969,35.89,47.541,52.462
        c43.407,43.407,74.809,98.79,127.394,133.067c44.3,28.876,85.672,49.923,138.364,58.69c69.464,11.559,124.444,2.54,191.202-16.422
        c104.527-29.689,201.769-76.793,289.516-139.937c42.764-30.773,77.666-72.729,122.62-99.768
        c50.301-30.254,105.492-64.867,159.904-86.632c92.434-39.106,181.063-100.788,251.25-171.875
        c31.896-32.304,66.448-72.631,77.125-117.75c11.867-50.149,19.56-98.736,21.625-150.375c0-54.127,4.634-111.463,6.963-166.259
        c2.441-57.438,3.972-113.243,13.297-170c7.623-46.402,20.744-87.695,56.294-120.587c31.39-29.043,76.555-65.571,94.946-104.654
        c8.934-18.985,24.678-32.756,32.98-52.139c11.043-25.779,11.248-54.254,13.289-81.738c1.946-26.211-1.156-52.432,0.675-78.882
        c1.963-28.351,9.619-56.153,9.431-84.616c-0.293-44.235-21.954-87.451-44.875-124.125c-43.331-54.164-91.033-2.819-125,36
        c-50.949,62.271-118.999,159.005-109.5,244.5c2.411,21.704-8.296,32.208-18.25,50.25c-12.092,21.917-19.175,43.347-21.25,68.25
        c-4.311,30.171-0.273,59.368,2.68,89.448c1.227,12.493,4.32,27.231,4.32,39.552c0,6.844-5.353,12.754-3.578,8.601
        c2.911-1.966,3.771-0.833,2.578,3.399c-47.409-37.928-40.657-126.818-47.125-180c-2.167-17.817-4.29-71.508-22.5-81.625
        c-14.396-7.998-15.077,62.01-14.344,67.875c4.491,35.93-16.116-1.506-21.92-14.324c-13.666-30.178-17.265-64.605-24.111-96.822
        c-13.661-64.283-29.435-126.601-46-190.104c-8.623-25.868-28.964-49.228-44.814-70.852c-19.866-27.101-35.539-56.868-54.958-84.279
        c-36.979-52.197-70.151-98.792-115.228-143.869c-20.548-20.547-43.361-38.965-70.75-49.125
        c-39.084-14.499-27.718,21.271-24.408,45.627c9.404,69.213,83.619,85.898,110.945,140.058c-0.539-1.26-0.539-1.26,0,0
        c-1.549-1.119-2.694-2.546-3.437-4.28c1.728,0.956,2.873,2.382,3.437,4.28c-33.145-29.063-68.993-52.085-104.443-77.779
        c-32.626-23.646-76.713-40.15-105.344-68.781c-39.09-19.545-76.505-50.088-110-78c-18.519-16.835-36.408-32.652-51.625-52.5
        c-12.863-16.777-26.937-41.062-41.375-55.5c-29.586-29.586-45.693-72.107-77-99.5c-33.206-29.055-72.169-45.084-111-64.5
        c-8.22-5.48-20.368-4.095-29-11c-20.746-10.373-3.499,43.453-1.75,48c8.116,21.102,20.279,41.774,29.222,62.936
        c2.116,5.007,34.684,48.175,34.778,47.939c-1.561,3.903-68.28-71.214-78.242-77.869c-36.59-24.448-84.849-50.89-101.447-94.749
        c-15.672-41.412,19.921-103.632,37.257-140.601c12.106-25.815,19.211-54.101,35.163-78.042c16.457-24.699,38.841-44.255,59.1-65.657
        c-22.636-21.361-105.591,48.52-120.634,64.608c-43.661,46.697-67.815,102.46-93.739,159.881
        C911.3,1007.47,759.609,995.49,673.057,1077.379c-43.074,40.753-77.728,111.422-80.61,170.498
        c-1.651,33.851-10.257,65.288-8.369,99.569c1.971,35.768-3.779,67.888-13.952,102.104c-19.856,66.789-41.101,122.66-77.932,181.85
        c-17.076,27.443-28.568,57.338-43.268,85.993c-15.072,29.38-36.854,41.532-43.636,76.335
        c-5.878-80.343-32.141-157.622-35.634-238.854c-3.732-86.805,28.114-152.401,50.771-233.371
        c22.175-79.244,68.332-142.288,73.671-227.543c2.401-38.335,13.992-73.532,26.493-109.548c15-43.214,17.744-79.896,44.428-119.309
        c45.189-66.744,99.946-120.074,166.354-165.686c32.482-22.311,67.216-37.679,100.899-57.378
        c36.212-21.179,68.07-47.756,106.292-66.032c73.732-35.256,152.973-39.133,233.839-46.663c22.458-2.091,57.163-15.8,79.567-9.993
        c9.649,2.501-16.527,53.048-15.829,66.824c-0.201-3.983,147.514-32.421,157.959-33.811c52.149-6.94,103.896-17.357,156.799-13.956
        c52.464,3.374,86.372,50.615,122.926,81.772c36.808,31.374,63.902,78.269,103.809,104.334
        c41.339,27.001,96.697,43.496,144.006,56.327c48.201,13.074,97.097,29.991,140.361,54.841
        c49.342,28.342,106.265,43.365,157.159,69.197c49.727,25.238,86.129,50.654,108.619,103.171
        c10.992,25.668,27.36,46.758,36.442,73.71c9.544,28.323,15.726,57.79,17.251,87.674c0.828,16.208-4.857,38.451,4.994,52.745
        c11.554,16.763,25.008,31.074,41.293,43.17c12.156,9.029,18.786,31.155,30.554,42.878c16.379,16.319,27.618,31.697,37.166,52.68
        c40.238,88.449,68.993,190.7,49.853,289.211c-9.129,46.981-20.9,94.993-32.856,141.342c-7.486,29.021-21.176,53.734-31.518,81.433
        c-9.207,24.645-12.56,50.123-17.314,76.016"/>
      </svg>
```

Comment: This works, but only cycles through 2 classes. Perhaps I was unclear in the question, but I am trying to cycle through 4, so the "pen" never jumps (path A>>B>>C>>D). It is split into 4 events because they need to trigger other things, otherwise i would toggle switch between two path classes which draw and then undraw.

Comment: Sounds like you need an array of those 4 class names then, and then you can cycle through them - see edit

Answer (score 0):

No js needed, simply merge your 4 animations in a single one.

```css
.patha {
  stroke-dasharray: 13672.7;
  animation: dash 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  33% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 13672.7;
  }
  66% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -13672.7;
  }  
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 3027.621 4035.496" enable-background="new 0 0 150 200" xml:space="preserve">
      <path id="path" class="patha" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="16" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M413.078,1768.305
        c-24.633,50.051-0.718,112.339,6.712,163.942c9.629,66.869,23.438,133.097,36.056,199.496
        c22.431,118.04,30.003,240.334,26.476,359.948c-3.251,110.267,14.797,239.577,71.273,335.987
        c14.709,25.109,29.367,50.25,43.714,75.568c9.666,19.331,28.359,31.145,41,48c14.109,20.522,29.366,40.521,48,57.186
        c23.089,20.648,51.639,30.456,74.625,51.064c20.852,18.695,45.92,32.317,66.834,51.288c17.762,16.109,30.969,35.89,47.541,52.462
        c43.407,43.407,74.809,98.79,127.394,133.067c44.3,28.876,85.672,49.923,138.364,58.69c69.464,11.559,124.444,2.54,191.202-16.422
        c104.527-29.689,201.769-76.793,289.516-139.937c42.764-30.773,77.666-72.729,122.62-99.768
        c50.301-30.254,105.492-64.867,159.904-86.632c92.434-39.106,181.063-100.788,251.25-171.875
        c31.896-32.304,66.448-72.631,77.125-117.75c11.867-50.149,19.56-98.736,21.625-150.375c0-54.127,4.634-111.463,6.963-166.259
        c2.441-57.438,3.972-113.243,13.297-170c7.623-46.402,20.744-87.695,56.294-120.587c31.39-29.043,76.555-65.571,94.946-104.654
        c8.934-18.985,24.678-32.756,32.98-52.139c11.043-25.779,11.248-54.254,13.289-81.738c1.946-26.211-1.156-52.432,0.675-78.882
        c1.963-28.351,9.619-56.153,9.431-84.616c-0.293-44.235-21.954-87.451-44.875-124.125c-43.331-54.164-91.033-2.819-125,36
        c-50.949,62.271-118.999,159.005-109.5,244.5c2.411,21.704-8.296,32.208-18.25,50.25c-12.092,21.917-19.175,43.347-21.25,68.25
        c-4.311,30.171-0.273,59.368,2.68,89.448c1.227,12.493,4.32,27.231,4.32,39.552c0,6.844-5.353,12.754-3.578,8.601
        c2.911-1.966,3.771-0.833,2.578,3.399c-47.409-37.928-40.657-126.818-47.125-180c-2.167-17.817-4.29-71.508-22.5-81.625
        c-14.396-7.998-15.077,62.01-14.344,67.875c4.491,35.93-16.116-1.506-21.92-14.324c-13.666-30.178-17.265-64.605-24.111-96.822
        c-13.661-64.283-29.435-126.601-46-190.104c-8.623-25.868-28.964-49.228-44.814-70.852c-19.866-27.101-35.539-56.868-54.958-84.279
        c-36.979-52.197-70.151-98.792-115.228-143.869c-20.548-20.547-43.361-38.965-70.75-49.125
        c-39.084-14.499-27.718,21.271-24.408,45.627c9.404,69.213,83.619,85.898,110.945,140.058c-0.539-1.26-0.539-1.26,0,0
        c-1.549-1.119-2.694-2.546-3.437-4.28c1.728,0.956,2.873,2.382,3.437,4.28c-33.145-29.063-68.993-52.085-104.443-77.779
        c-32.626-23.646-76.713-40.15-105.344-68.781c-39.09-19.545-76.505-50.088-110-78c-18.519-16.835-36.408-32.652-51.625-52.5
        c-12.863-16.777-26.937-41.062-41.375-55.5c-29.586-29.586-45.693-72.107-77-99.5c-33.206-29.055-72.169-45.084-111-64.5
        c-8.22-5.48-20.368-4.095-29-11c-20.746-10.373-3.499,43.453-1.75,48c8.116,21.102,20.279,41.774,29.222,62.936
        c2.116,5.007,34.684,48.175,34.778,47.939c-1.561,3.903-68.28-71.214-78.242-77.869c-36.59-24.448-84.849-50.89-101.447-94.749
        c-15.672-41.412,19.921-103.632,37.257-140.601c12.106-25.815,19.211-54.101,35.163-78.042c16.457-24.699,38.841-44.255,59.1-65.657
        c-22.636-21.361-105.591,48.52-120.634,64.608c-43.661,46.697-67.815,102.46-93.739,159.881
        C911.3,1007.47,759.609,995.49,673.057,1077.379c-43.074,40.753-77.728,111.422-80.61,170.498
        c-1.651,33.851-10.257,65.288-8.369,99.569c1.971,35.768-3.779,67.888-13.952,102.104c-19.856,66.789-41.101,122.66-77.932,181.85
        c-17.076,27.443-28.568,57.338-43.268,85.993c-15.072,29.38-36.854,41.532-43.636,76.335
        c-5.878-80.343-32.141-157.622-35.634-238.854c-3.732-86.805,28.114-152.401,50.771-233.371
        c22.175-79.244,68.332-142.288,73.671-227.543c2.401-38.335,13.992-73.532,26.493-109.548c15-43.214,17.744-79.896,44.428-119.309
        c45.189-66.744,99.946-120.074,166.354-165.686c32.482-22.311,67.216-37.679,100.899-57.378
        c36.212-21.179,68.07-47.756,106.292-66.032c73.732-35.256,152.973-39.133,233.839-46.663c22.458-2.091,57.163-15.8,79.567-9.993
        c9.649,2.501-16.527,53.048-15.829,66.824c-0.201-3.983,147.514-32.421,157.959-33.811c52.149-6.94,103.896-17.357,156.799-13.956
        c52.464,3.374,86.372,50.615,122.926,81.772c36.808,31.374,63.902,78.269,103.809,104.334
        c41.339,27.001,96.697,43.496,144.006,56.327c48.201,13.074,97.097,29.991,140.361,54.841
        c49.342,28.342,106.265,43.365,157.159,69.197c49.727,25.238,86.129,50.654,108.619,103.171
        c10.992,25.668,27.36,46.758,36.442,73.71c9.544,28.323,15.726,57.79,17.251,87.674c0.828,16.208-4.857,38.451,4.994,52.745
        c11.554,16.763,25.008,31.074,41.293,43.17c12.156,9.029,18.786,31.155,30.554,42.878c16.379,16.319,27.618,31.697,37.166,52.68
        c40.238,88.449,68.993,190.7,49.853,289.211c-9.129,46.981-20.9,94.993-32.856,141.342c-7.486,29.021-21.176,53.734-31.518,81.433
        c-9.207,24.645-12.56,50.123-17.314,76.016"/>
      </svg>
```

Comment: this doesn't allow for on animationend events every quarter cycle which was the intention

Comment: @nutclump I can't guess your intentions though.

Comment: I thought I added why I was separating it but it looks like I didn't, just did.